# How to apply blur to a background styled with the body selector

Tags: html, css

I am making a program and with CSS and am trying to blur the background.

The CSS (snippet):

```css
body {
    background: some background i got from css-pattern
}

#blur.active > :not(#completion_popup) {
    filter: blur(20px);
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

The HTML (snippet):

```html
<body>
    <container id="blur">
        <!-- Random stuff for my webpage layout --->
        
        <div id="completion_popup">
            <!-- Stuff for my popup --->
        </div>
    </container>
</body>
```

And no, adding `id="blur"` to the body did not work.

Currently, all the container content is blurred except for the background (the popup shouldn't be blurred).

Anyone have any ideas on how to blur the background?

Comment: Have you tried `backdrop-filter`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: Are you trying to blur only the background, as your description suggests, or are you trying to blur everything in container except for completion-popup as your CSS suggests?

Comment: @DustInComp Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried it but it did nothing. I noticed that the popup's transition into the page was laggy though... strange.

Comment: @AHaworth I am trying to blur everything except for the completion popup. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Once you've blurred an element everything within it will be blurred as you have found. Any reason not to take the popup outside of the container and position it?

Comment: @AHaworth I think I played around with that, yeah, but it was annoying and I decided to keep it in the container. Why do you care lol? I also tried applying this concept to the background by putting it into the container but it stuffed everything up, so that's why I'm asking here for an actual solution.

Comment: If you keep it in the container it will get blurred  if the container is blurred..